# How to set success and failure handlers in OAuth2 WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux, spring-oauth2

In Spring Web (non-reactive), we can set the success and failure handlers for oauth2login as below:

```
http.oauth2Login()
    .successHandler(oauth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
    .failureHandler(oauth2AuthenticationFailureHandler)
```

But in WebFlux, we don't have these methods. When I looked at `ServerHttpSecurity.configure`, I see that the handlers are hardcoded:

```java
protected void configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    ...

    RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler redirectHandler = new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(redirectHandler);
    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> onAuthenticationFailure(WebFilterExchange webFilterExchange,
                AuthenticationException exception) {
            return Mono.error(exception);
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Do we have plans to make these configurable in a near-future Spring version? Should I create a ticket for this? And, for now, what'd be a way to override these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring version 5.2 there is a way to set authentication success and failure handlers. [ServerHttpSecurity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.java). under `OAuth2LoginSpec`. You need to update your dependencies.